# Orthogonal regression that minimizes absolute error instead of squared error

Tags: total-least-squares, least-absolute-deviations

Fitting a line through 3D points is usually done by orthogonal least squares (aka "total least squares"), i.e., by minimizing the mean squared orthogonal distance between the points and the line. This problem has a closed form solution $\vec{m}+t\vec{d}$ where $\vec{m}$ is the mean of all points and $\vec{d}$ the first principal component.

As this solution is very sensitive to outliers, I wonder whether there is also a solution known to the problem of minimizing the absolute orthogonal distances. And is there a software library that addresses this problem (I guess that minimizing a non-differentiable function might numerically unstable).

Note that this question (despite the title) is actually not about "regression" (predicting a value), but about fitting a line through points with no variable representing a "response".

Comment: It sounds like your *real* need is for [robust PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_principal_component_analysis).

Comment: @whuber Looks like something that is worth a try! There even is an R package *rpca* avaulable. If I understand the given example correctly, the PCA is then applied to the low rank component of the decomposition.

Comment: The line you seek corresponds to the first (robust) PC, not the last.  In your comment you might be thinking of fitting a codimension-1 hypersurface to $d$-dimensional points, which would correspond to a regression model for a univariate response.